# EF Add method Identity Column value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, out, ref

I may sound stupid question to you, but I really want to know it.

in Entity Framework (EF) on context class **DbSet** when we call **Add(object)** method , how it update the Id column on entity.  I mean if its using "REF" and "OUT" we can understand how it update the ID field but here without using REF and OUT how it can under the object property.??

```
//model.ID   -- here its zero
context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();
//model.ID   -- here its no zero
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained much more thoroughly in the [C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et(v=vs.90).aspx) types, but here the gist of it:

1. Value types are items like `int`, `bool`, any `struct`, etc.  These are blocks of memory that hold a distinct value.
2. Reference types are items like `string`, `object`, any `class`, etc.  These are actually just 'references' to the block of memory holding their value.

If you pass a value type as a parameter to a method, then that value is essentially copied into a new block of memory and the original value cannot be modified by the code in the method.

```
public static void Main()
{

    int myInt = 5;

    Console.WriteLine(myInt);
    ChangeMe(myInt);
    Console.WriteLine(myInt);
}

public static void ChangeMe(int i)
{
    i = 7;
}
// Outputs:
// 5
// 5
```

In order to modify a value type, you have to use the "ref" or an "out" parameter.

```
public static void Main()
{

    int myInt = 5;

    Console.WriteLine(myInt);
    ChangeMe(ref myInt);
    Console.WriteLine(myInt);
}

public static void ChangeMe(ref int i)
{
    i = 7;
}
// Outputs:
// 5
// 7
```

This, however, does not apply to types that are already reference types.  Typically, in entity framework you work with types that are set up as `class` objects.  These are reference types by default.  Passing a reference type to a method does not 'copy' it like a value type does, the method instead gets access to the original object.  This is because you are merely passing a location to where that memory lives.  This manifests in allowing the method to modify the values on the class.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{

    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    myclass.MyInt = 5;

    Console.WriteLine(myclass.MyInt);
    ChangeMe(myClass);
    Console.WriteLine(myclass.MyInt);
}

public static void ChangeMe(MyClass i)
{
    i.MyInt = 7;
}
// Outputs:
// 5
// 7
```

Comment: +1 thanks.  Actually the mistake I was doing is like in your case I was reinitializing MyClass object again instead changing the MyInt only.  Thanks :)